# How can I change the var value in JavaScript when I input a number on the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a simple code that can be used to calculate the area of a circle by using the radius (A = pi r2) but I want to change the value of the 'radius' by inserting a number on the **browser**, for example inserting 9 and clicking on the run, to show the result. This is the JS code:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function runScript() {
'use strict';
    var radius = 4;
    var result = (Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
};
```

Comment: Put use strict at the top. It doesn't go inside a function (afaik).

Comment: Use a different input, like the range input.

Comment: Well instead of `var radius = 4;` do `var radius = document.getElementById("myInput").value;` and make sure there is an input with the ID `myInput` is in your HTML.

Comment: its not good practice to put `'use strict'` into the global scope (afaik)

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks for the info

Comment: @gottz why is that?

Comment: @evolutionxbox because it would override behavior of included libraries that might not be strict mode compatible. (there are for example certain template engines that use `which` (deprecated in strict mode) and other stuff.

Comment: common practice is to just throw all your code into a closure and add `'use strict'` on top of that closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an onclick listener. You can use either js or html events. If you want to do it with html events; add `onclick="runScript()"` on your button element. Then define an element where to put your radius input and one where to put your output:

```
<input type="number" id="my-input" />
<button id="myButton" onclick="runScript()"></button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

And in you runScript() do this;

`var radius = document.getElementById("my-input").value;`

Moreover, move the `use strict` at the beginning of your file, not inside your function. Final version should be something like:

```
'use strict';
function runScript() {
    var radius = document.getElementById("my-input").value;
    var result = (Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
};
```

Don't forget to include your javascript source into the html page.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var radius = document.getElementById("radius").value;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="radius" placeholder="radius">
```

using input type you are getting radius from user
then use var radius in JScript

Comment: `getElementById` should be `document.getElementById`. Please run your snippet before posting your answer.